# JSON desererialize, GSON, android, error

Tags: java, android, json, gson, deserialization

I got ArrayList of custom object MyList. MyList is HashMap. MyList contains ArrayList of custom object MyListElement (it's HashMap too). After GSON serialization it look like this (little correct for better vision):

```
{
        "list buyed list": [],
        "list name": "item1",
        "list quantity": "Не купленных: 0",
        "list main list": [
                        {
                        "listelement quantity": 4.0,
                        "listelement sum": 1.0,
                        "listelement name": "item 1"
                        },
                        {
                        "listelement quantity": 2.0,
                        "listelement sum": 2.0,
                        "listelement name": "item 2"
                        },
                        {
                        "listelement quantity": 4.0,
                        "listelement sum": 3.0,
                        "listelement name": "item 3"
                        }
                        ]
        },
        {
        "list buyed list": [],
        "list name": "item2",
        "list quantity": "Не купленных: 0",
        "list main list": [
                        {
                        "listelement quantity": 5.0,
                        "listelement sum": 1.0,
                        "listelement name": "item 4"
                        },
                        {
                        "listelement quantity": 4.0,
                        "listelement sum": 7.0,
                        "listelement name": "item 5"
                        },
                        {
                        "listelement quantity": 6.0,
                        "listelement sum": 3.0,
                        "listelement name": "item 6"
                        }
        ]
        }
```

But if i try deserialize it - i get error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.llaerto.mysecondbuylist.MyList.
```

My Deserialize code:

```
public void gsonGetFromSerialize() {
        String json = "";
        try {
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/mydb.json");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                json = json + line + "\n";
            }
            Log.d("TAG", json);
            fileReader.close();
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyList>>() {}.getType();
        list = new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);
    }
```

Sorry for language, and dummy questions. Thanks for help.

MyList class code:

```
public class MyList extends HashMap<String, Object> implements Serializable{
    public static final String LIST_NAME = "list name";
    public static final String LIST_LIST_MAIN = "list main list";
    public static final String LIST_LIST_BUYED = "list buyed list";
    public static final String LIST_QUANTITY = "list quantity";

    public MyList(String name) {
        this.put(LIST_NAME, name);
        this.put(LIST_LIST_MAIN, new ArrayList<MyListElement>());
        this.put(LIST_LIST_BUYED, new ArrayList<MyListElement>());
        this.put(LIST_QUANTITY, "Не купленных: " +  0);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (String) this.get(LIST_NAME);
    }

    public void getSum() {
        int i = ((ArrayList) this.get(LIST_LIST_MAIN)).size();
        this.put(LIST_QUANTITY, "Не купленных: " + i);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.get(LIST_NAME).toString();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.put(LIST_NAME, name);
    }

    public void toListAdd(MyListElement element) {
        ArrayList<MyListElement> list;
        list = (ArrayList<MyListElement>) this.get(LIST_LIST_MAIN);
        list.add(element);
        this.put(LIST_LIST_MAIN, list);
    }
}
```

MyListElement class code:

```
public class MyListElement extends HashMap<String, Object> implements Serializable {
    public static final String LIST_ELEMENT_NAME = "listelement name";
    public static final String LIST_ELEMENT_QUANTITY = "listelement quantity";
    public static final String LIST_ELEMENT_COLOR = "listelement color";
    public static final String LIST_ELEMENT_SUM = "listelement sum";

    public MyListElement(String name, float quantity, float sum) {
        this.put(LIST_ELEMENT_NAME, name);
        this.put(LIST_ELEMENT_QUANTITY, quantity);
        this.put(LIST_ELEMENT_SUM, sum);
        //this.put(LIST_ELEMENT_COLOR, color);
    }
}
```

Sorry for that i didn't it when posted first.

Comment: Can you share the code for MyList class too !

Comment: Your json file still has errors. You can always validate your json files using online tools. Such has [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see any benefit of using Map's to represent json and do not get it why you want to use it that way. IMHO, Using classes will be much better to understand. So please take this answer as a proposal. And I hope somebody will use it in the future.

First you need to create your root class. Lets call it `RootItem`. Your Json is ( actually looks like) an array of `RootItem`.

```
public class RootItem {

    @SerializedName("list buyed list")
    private Collection<String> listBuyedList;

    @SerializedName("list name")
    private String listName;

    @SerializedName("list quantity")
    private String listQuality;

    @SerializedName("list main list")
    private Collection<MainListItem> listMainList;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

Your `RootItem` class has its own arrays. First one is look like a string array. And last one is an object array. Lets call this object `MainListItem`.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class MainListItem {

    @SerializedName("listelement quantity")
    private Integer listElementQuantity;

    @SerializedName("listelement sum")
    private Integer listElementSum;

    @SerializedName("listelement name")
    private String listElementName;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

Finally you need to parse your JSON file as a `Collection<RootItem>` since its an array of `RootItem` objects.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.util.Collection;

public class GsonApp {

    private static final String TEST_JSON = "[\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "        \"list buyed list\": [],\n" +
            "        \"list name\": \"item1\",\n" +
            "        \"list quantity\": \"Не купленных: 0\",\n" +
            "        \"list main list\": [\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"listelement quantity\": 4,\n" +
            "                \"listelement sum\": 1,\n" +
            "                \"listelement name\": \"item 1\"\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"listelement quantity\": 2,\n" +
            "                \"listelement sum\": 2,\n" +
            "                \"listelement name\": \"item 2\"\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"listelement quantity\": 4,\n" +
            "                \"listelement sum\": 3,\n" +
            "                \"listelement name\": \"item 3\"\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "        ]\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "        \"list buyed list\": [],\n" +
            "        \"list name\": \"item2\",\n" +
            "        \"list quantity\": \"Не купленных: 0\",\n" +
            "        \"list main list\": [\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"listelement quantity\": 5,\n" +
            "                \"listelement sum\": 1,\n" +
            "                \"listelement name\": \"item 4\"\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"listelement quantity\": 4,\n" +
            "                \"listelement sum\": 7,\n" +
            "                \"listelement name\": \"item 5\"\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"listelement quantity\": 6,\n" +
            "                \"listelement sum\": 3,\n" +
            "                \"listelement name\": \"item 6\"\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "        ]\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "]";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        final Collection<RootItem> rootItems = gson.fromJson(TEST_JSON, new TypeToken<Collection<RootItem>>() {
        }.getType());
        System.out.println(rootItems);
    }
}
```

### Update

If you really want to handle maps. You can do it like this.

Lets create a root class again and call it `RootClass`.

```
public class RootClass implements Map<String, Object> {

    private transient Map<String, Object> inner;

    public RootClass() {
        this.inner = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Collection<Map<String, Object>> getMainListElement(){
        final Object object = this.inner.get("list main list");
        return object == null ? null : (Collection<Map<String, Object>>)object;
    }


    // Delegated methods
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return inner.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return inner.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return inner.containsKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return inner.containsValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(Object key) {
        return inner.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Object put(String key, Object value) {
        return inner.put(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public Object remove(Object key) {
        return inner.remove(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends String, ?> m) {
        inner.putAll(m);
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        inner.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> keySet() {
        return inner.keySet();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Object> values() {
        return inner.values();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<String, Object>> entrySet() {
        return inner.entrySet();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return inner.equals(o);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return inner.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getOrDefault(Object key, Object defaultValue) {
        return inner.getOrDefault(key, defaultValue);
    }

    @Override
    public void forEach(BiConsumer<? super String, ? super Object> action) {
        inner.forEach(action);
    }

    @Override
    public void replaceAll(BiFunction<? super String, ? super Object, ?> function) {
        inner.replaceAll(function);
    }

    @Override
    public Object putIfAbsent(String key, Object value) {
        return inner.putIfAbsent(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object key, Object value) {
        return inner.remove(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean replace(String key, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        return inner.replace(key, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(String key, Object value) {
        return inner.replace(key, value);
    }

    @Override
    public Object computeIfAbsent(String key, Function<? super String, ?> mappingFunction) {
        return inner.computeIfAbsent(key, mappingFunction);
    }

    @Override
    public Object computeIfPresent(String key, BiFunction<? super String, ? super Object, ?> remappingFunction) {
        return inner.computeIfPresent(key, remappingFunction);
    }

    @Override
    public Object compute(String key, BiFunction<? super String, ? super Object, ?> remappingFunction) {
        return inner.compute(key, remappingFunction);
    }

    @Override
    public Object merge(String key, Object value, BiFunction<? super Object, ? super Object, ?> remappingFunction) {
        return inner.merge(key, value, remappingFunction);
    }
}
```

But still your json is a Collection so we need to use Collection to get data to our map.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    final Collection<RootClass> items = gson.fromJson(TEST_JSON, new TypeToken<Collection<RootClass>>() {
    }.getType());
    System.out.println(items);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I need HashMap because i use SimpleAdapter for ListView (android) :(

Comment: @llaerto Which one do you need as map?

Comment: I use SimpleAdapter for main ListView each use list Name and Quantity. And when i open this MyList will be used more 2 SimpleAdapters - 1 for main list and 1 for buyed list (both lists formed by MyListElement items). It's my first app, i just study, and may be i'm doing now real bad app :(

Comment: @llaerto I am not good at Android. As far as I know you can write your own adapter. Instead using `SimpleAdapter` you can write your own adapter for `RootItem` and `MainListItem` for example. Than you can use them in your view.

Comment: @llaerto You may want to use an ArrayAdapter instead of a SimpleAdapter--that's more typical for ListViews and doesn't require a map. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20466964/android-arrayadapter-and-jsonarray and maybe also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708633/how-to-get-a-jsonarray-to-populate-into-a-listactivitys-listview

Comment: Thanks, bhdrkn, i forgot about custom adapters. I think it will be good. hBrent, but with ArrayAdapter i can't use custom view for my list?

Comment: @llaerto I don't know what you mean by "use custom view" for your list. You said you're using a ListView--are you extending ListView? Your MyList class is not a view, if that's what you're referring to.